# Executing external java jar, from another java application

Tags: java, windows, jar, cmd, runtime

I have a java application (system a) that executes a java jar (system b). It's a window and when I click on a button it excecutes this command:

```
 Runtime obj = Runtime.getRuntime();

 Process proc = obj.exec("cmd.exe /c javaw -cp . -jar " + rutaFiles + "/Sistema_Monitor` /SistemaAlmacen/SistemaAlmacen.jar " + idCoordinador + " " + pass + " " + nomRed);`
```

What happens is that when the secon process(system b) (I don't really know if it is a different process) starts, it gets stuck, and only run ok if I close the first process(system a), it's like some dependence or something. Is there a way to execute that jar separate?
What I'm doing to resolve it, I don't like it, but it works. I open the second process(system b) via the first one (system a), then open a new process(another instance of system a) , then I close the first process(system a) and that works fine. But I don't think that's right.

My operative system is Windows (this System has to run on Windows XP and also Windows 7)
I use java 1.6 and mysql. So guys do you have some ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Process proc = obj.exec("javaw -cp . -jar ....
```

without calling cmd.exe

Comment: Hi! I did it jus now and it was the same problem :/